# curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number

Tags: windows-10, curl, filezilla, ftps

I am using curl 7.85.0 under Windows 10 x64 and try to connect to a FTPS Filezilla server 1.5.1 using TLS V1.3 in passive mode. The server listen on port 635 on another Win10 computer.

The command line I use is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Curl\bin\curl.exe" -tlsv1.3 -v --ftp-pasv --user John:JPass123 ftps://192.168.1.57:635/Philippe
```

This doesn't work at all. The reply I get is:

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.57:635...
* Connected to 192.168.1.57 (192.168.1.57) port 635 (#0)
*  CAfile: C:\Program Files\Curl\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (3230) (IN), , Unknown (50):
* error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```

The Filezilla log shows:

```
<Date> Info [Type] Message
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Trace] Session 0x295a692cd30 with ID 26 created.
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220-FileZilla Server 1.5.1
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220-Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220 Welcome to Overbyte I7-PC FTP server
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Error] Control channel closed with error from source 1. Reason: EINVAL - Invalid argument passed.
<02-10-22 11:28:13> FTP Session 26 192.168.1.6 [Trace] Session 0x295a692cd30 with ID 26 destroyed.
```

When trying the same server with Filezilla client running on the same computer as curl, everything is OK.The server log is:

```
<Date> Info [Type] Message
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] Session 0x295a692cd30 with ID 27 created.
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220-FileZilla Server 1.5.1
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220-Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Response] 220 Welcome to Overbyte I7-PC FTP server
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Command] AUTH TLS
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Response] 234 Using authentication type TLS.
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::server_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] TLS Handshake successful
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Trace] Protocol: TLS1.3, Key exchange: ECDHE-SECP384R1-ECDSA-SECP256R1-SHA256, Cipher: AES-256-GCM, MAC: AEAD, ALPN: x-filezilla-ftp
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Command] USER Philippe
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Response] 331 Please, specify the password.
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 [Command] PASS ****
<02-10-22 11:31:13> FTP Session 27 192.168.1.6 Philippe [Response] 230 Login successful.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This error may occur if you're trying to connect via SSL to a port that's serving non-SSL.